# cypher: how to return distinct relationship types?

Tags: graph, neo4j, relationship, cypher

How to return the distinct relationship types from all paths in `cypher`?

Example query:

```
MATCH p=(a:Philosopher)-[*]->(b:SchoolType)
RETURN DISTINCT EXTRACT( r in RELATIONSHIPS(p)| type(r) ) as RelationshipTypes
```

This returns a collection for each path p.

I would like to return a single collection contain the distinct relationship types across all collections.

Here is a link to a graph gist to run the query-

http://gist.neo4j.org/?7851642

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might first collect all relationships on the matched path to a collection "allr", and then get the collection of distinct type(r) from the collection of all relationships,

```
MATCH p=(a:Philosopher)-[rel*]->(b:SchoolType) 
WITH collect(rel) AS allr 
RETURN Reduce(allDistR =[], rcol IN allr | 
              reduce(distR = allDistR, r IN rcol | 
                     distR +  CASE WHEN type(r) IN distR  THEN []  ELSE type(r) END 
                    )
              )
```

Note, each element 'rcol' in the collection "allr" is in turn a **collection** of relationships on each matched path.

Comment: This works perfectly.  I did not consider using multiple reduces to perform nested loop like processing or using CASE to append an empty collection if the relationship type exists.  Thank you.

Comment: I would prefer to return a single collection rather than a collection of collections.  My attempts to do this have produced results that surprised me and I have not found a solution.  This is not a problem, and I am happy with the query as it.  But it is a puzzle for me.  In embedded mode, if I HEAD(col of col) I get a single element rather than the first collection.  if I do a range (col of col)[0..1000] I still get a collection of collections.  Thoughts?

Comment: I tried the head function with the collection "allr" and it did return a collection rather than a single element. perhaps because of different versions? I tried with the version 2.0.0-M05.

Comment: I am using 2.0.0-RC  When I head "allr" I get a collection of collection that contain only the first collection in the set.  But this is still a collection of collections.  I get [[Relationship[5], Relationship[11]]] rather than [Relationship[5], Relationship[11]]